# Chainerでオートエンコーダーを作る際にTypeError: Unsupported type <class 'NoneType'>というエラー

Tags: python, 機械学習, 深層学習, chainer

Chainerをつかって、pythonで自己符号器をつくろうとしています。次のようなコードを書いて実行しました。

```
class Autoencoder(Chain):
    def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
       with self.init_scope():
           self.l1 = L.Linear(3,2)
           self.l2 = L.Linear(2,3)
    def __call__(self,x):
       h1 = self.l1(x)
       h2 = self.l2(h1) 

       return h2

class Dataset(dataset.DatasetMixin):
    def __init__(self,number_of_data, show_initial = False):

       noise_level = 1

       self.data = np.zeros((number_of_data,3),dtype = np.float32)

       OA_vector = np.array([3,2,1])
       OB_vector = np.array([2,-1,1])

       t = np.random.uniform(-0.5,0.5,number_of_data)
       s = np.random.uniform(-0.5,0.5,number_of_data)

       for i in range(0,number_of_data):
           noise = np.random.uniform(-noise_level, noise_level,3)
           self.data[i] = t[i]*OA_vector + s[i]*OB_vector + noise

   def __len__(self):
        return self.data.shape[0]

   def get_example(self,idx):
       return self.data[idx]

if __name__ == "__main__":

    n_epoch = 5
    batch_size = 100

    number_of_data = 1000 #データ数
    train_data = Dataset(number_of_data,False)

    model = Autoencoder()

    optimizer = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.05).setup(model)
    train_iter = iterators.SerialIterator(train_data,batch_size)

    updater = training.StandardUpdater(train_iter,optimizer,device=0)
    trainer = training.Trainer(updater,(n_epoch,"epoch"),out="result")

    trainer.run()
```

なお、Dataset(number_of_data,False)はnumber_of_dataの数の3次元ベクトルを収得する関数です。FalseをTrueにすると得たdataを可視化できます。

実行すると次のようなエラーが生じます。原因は何でしょうか。

```
Exception in main training loop: Unsupported type <class 'NoneType'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/trainer.py", line 308, in run
    update()
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/standard_updater.py", line 149, in update
    self.update_core()
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/standard_updater.py", line 164, in update_core
    optimizer.update(loss_func, in_arrays)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/optimizer.py", line 655, in update
    loss.backward(loss_scale=self._loss_scale)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/variable.py", line 966, in backward
    self._backward_main(retain_grad, loss_scale)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/variable.py", line 1095, in _backward_main
    target_input_indexes, out_grad, in_grad)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/function_node.py", line 548, in backward_accumulate
    gxs = self.backward(target_input_indexes, grad_outputs)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/functions/activation/relu.py", line 73, in backward
    return ReLUGrad2(y).apply((gy,))
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/function_node.py", line 258, in apply
    outputs = self.forward(in_data)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/function_node.py", line 368, in forward
    return self.forward_cpu(inputs)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/functions/activation/relu.py", line 97, in forward_cpu
    y = (self.b > 0) * inputs[0]
  File "cupy/core/core.pyx", line 1310, in cupy.core.core.ndarray.__mul__
  File "cupy/core/elementwise.pxi", line 753, in cupy.core.core.ufunc.__call__
  File "cupy/core/elementwise.pxi", line 68, in cupy.core.core._preprocess_args
Will finalize trainer extensions and updater before reraising the exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AC.py", line 71, in <module>
    trainer.run()
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/trainer.py", line 322, in run
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/trainer.py", line 308, in run
    update()
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/standard_updater.py", line 149, in update
    self.update_core()
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/standard_updater.py", line 164, in update_core
    optimizer.update(loss_func, in_arrays)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/optimizer.py", line 655, in update
    loss.backward(loss_scale=self._loss_scale)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/variable.py", line 966, in backward
    self._backward_main(retain_grad, loss_scale)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/variable.py", line 1095, in _backward_main
    target_input_indexes, out_grad, in_grad)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/function_node.py", line 548, in backward_accumulate
    gxs = self.backward(target_input_indexes, grad_outputs)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/functions/activation/relu.py", line 73, in backward
    return ReLUGrad2(y).apply((gy,))
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/function_node.py", line 258, in apply
    outputs = self.forward(in_data)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/function_node.py", line 368, in forward
    return self.forward_cpu(inputs)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/functions/activation/relu.py", line 97, in forward_cpu
    y = (self.b > 0) * inputs[0]
  File "cupy/core/core.pyx", line 1310, in cupy.core.core.ndarray.__mul__
  File "cupy/core/elementwise.pxi", line 753, in cupy.core.core.ufunc.__call__
  File "cupy/core/elementwise.pxi", line 68, in cupy.core.core._preprocess_args
TypeError: Unsupported type <class 'NoneType'>
```

ちなみに、trainer.run()をコメントアウトするとエラーは出ません（もちろん学習もはじまりませんが…)

cupyのエラーが出てるのでGPU関連かなと思って、

```
    updater = training.StandardUpdater(train_iter,optimizer,device=-1)
```

としてみたら今度は、

```
    Exception in main training loop: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'bool' and 'NoneType'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/trainer.py", line 308, in run
    update()
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/standard_updater.py", line 149, in update
    self.update_core()
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/standard_updater.py", line 164, in update_core
    optimizer.update(loss_func, in_arrays)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/optimizer.py", line 655, in update
    loss.backward(loss_scale=self._loss_scale)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/variable.py", line 966, in backward
    self._backward_main(retain_grad, loss_scale)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/variable.py", line 1095, in _backward_main
    target_input_indexes, out_grad, in_grad)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/function_node.py", line 548, in backward_accumulate
    gxs = self.backward(target_input_indexes, grad_outputs)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/functions/activation/relu.py", line 73, in backward
    return ReLUGrad2(y).apply((gy,))
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/function_node.py", line 258, in apply
    outputs = self.forward(in_data)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/function_node.py", line 368, in forward
    return self.forward_cpu(inputs)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/functions/activation/relu.py", line 97, in forward_cpu
    y = (self.b > 0) * inputs[0]
Will finalize trainer extensions and updater before reraising the exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AC.py", line 70, in <module>
    trainer.run()
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/trainer.py", line 322, in run
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/trainer.py", line 308, in run
    update()
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/standard_updater.py", line 149, in update
    self.update_core()
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/standard_updater.py", line 164, in update_core
    optimizer.update(loss_func, in_arrays)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/optimizer.py", line 655, in update
    loss.backward(loss_scale=self._loss_scale)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/variable.py", line 966, in backward
    self._backward_main(retain_grad, loss_scale)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/variable.py", line 1095, in _backward_main
    target_input_indexes, out_grad, in_grad)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/function_node.py", line 548, in backward_accumulate
    gxs = self.backward(target_input_indexes, grad_outputs)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/functions/activation/relu.py", line 73, in backward
    return ReLUGrad2(y).apply((gy,))
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/function_node.py", line 258, in apply
    outputs = self.forward(in_data)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/function_node.py", line 368, in forward
    return self.forward_cpu(inputs)
  File "/home/****/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/functions/activation/relu.py", line 97, in forward_cpu
    y = (self.b > 0) * inputs[0]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'bool' and 'NoneType'
```

というエラーが出ます。

Comment: 【FYI】この質問は
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53391404/autoencoder-in-chainer-issue
の質問者が同じ質問を日本語でしたものです

Answer (score 1):

正解データとloss functionが与えられていないためにエラーが起きています.
trainerを使わずに書くと

```
for batch in train_iter:
    con = chainer.dataset.concat_examples(batch) # dataset[0], dataset[1], ...を一つのarrayに入れる
    con = chainer.Variable(con) # arrayをchainer.Variableに入れる
    pred = model(con)　　　　　　 #推測する
    loss = F.mean_absolute_error(pred, con)　# 推測と正解データ(AEの場合入力そのもの)と比較する
    model.cleargrads() # 過去に計算されたgradientを初期化する
    loss.backward()　　# lossに対してgradientを計算する
    optimizer.update() # gradientに基づいてmodelを最適化する
```

というループで学習が実現できます.
trainerを使いたい場合にはchianer.links.Classifier(https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/chainer.links.Classifier.html) のコードなどを参考にして,modelとloss functionを結びつける新しいモデルを書くとよいと思います.
例えば,以下のようにです.

```
from chainer import reporter
class AEWrapper(Chain):

    def __init__(self, predictor,
                 lossfun=F.mean_absolute_error,):
        super(AEWrapper, self).__init__()
        self.lossfun = lossfun
        with self.init_scope():
            self.predictor = predictor

    def forward(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.y = None
        self.loss = None

        self.y = self.predictor(*args)
        self.loss = self.lossfun(self.y, *args)
        reporter.report({'loss': self.loss}, self)
        return self.loss
```

ところで,J.J.Sakurai(なつかしい)さんのコードでは終了すると学習結果も過程も消えてしまうので,適当にログを取ったり,プリントするようにするといいと思います.

```
n_epoch = 5
batch_size = 100
number_of_data = 1000 #データ数
train_data = Dataset(number_of_data,False)

model = Autoencoder()
model = AEWrapper(model)

optimizer = chainer.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.05).setup(model)
train_iter = chainer.iterators.SerialIterator(train_data,batch_size)

updater = chainer.training.StandardUpdater(train_iter,optimizer,device=0)
trainer = chainer.training.Trainer(updater,(n_epoch,"epoch"),out="result")
trainer.extend(extensions.LogReport(keys=["main/loss"],
                         trigger=training.triggers.IntervalTrigger(1, 'epoch')))
trainer.extend(extensions.PrintReport(['epoch', 'main/loss']),
                trigger=training.triggers.IntervalTrigger(1, 'epoch')) 
trainer.extend(extensions.snapshot_object(model,
                            'model_{.updater.iteration}.npz'), trigger=(1, 'epoch'))
trainer.run()
```

>

```
epoch       main/loss 
1           1.31194     
2           1.0665      
3           0.883515    
4           0.743101    
5           0.635571
```

Comment: 損失関数が定義されていない（Chainerにおいて損失はsize=1のVariableでなければならない）というのは正しいですが、おそらく質問者はGPUを使いたいのだと思うので、このコードだとその意図にそぐわないように思われます。
`concat_example`にはdevice引数があるので、それを明示したほうがわかりやすい（というよりはTrainerを使ったほうがわかりやすい）と思います。

Comment: ああ、確かにlossがどこにもないですね。これじゃいけませんね。。。